# Material UI DataGrid - how to tell which rows user has selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on creating a website using React and Material UI. I want to know which rows have been selected in my `DataGrid`.

I want to fill an array with the current selected rows using useState. I am attempting to do so in `handleRowSelection`.

Currently e.selection model is printing out the correct selected rows, but when I try and put the selected rows in my `useState` array it skips the first selected row.

For example: If I had selected row 2 and row 4 the `e.selection` model would print `["2","4"]` to the console but select would just print `["4"]`.

What am I missing? How come select doesn't have the first row selected?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
  { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
  { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
  {
    field: 'age',
    headerName: 'Age',
    type: 'number',
    width: 90,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.getValue('firstName') || ''} ${params.getValue('lastName') || ''}`,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
];

export default function DataGridDemo() {

 const [select, setSelection] = useState([]);

    const handleRowSelection = (e) => {
       
       // prints correct indexes of selected rows
        console.log(e.selectionModel);
        
        // missing the first row selected
        setSelection(e.selectionModel);
        console.log(select);

    }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid 
      rows={rows} 
      columns={columns} 
      pageSize={5} 
      checkboxSelection 
      NoRowsOverlay
      onSelectionModelChange = {handleRowSelection}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to access `select` right after you update it? I'm asking because maybe you can implement the same behaviour with a different approach.

Comment: I want to allow the user to delete rows of data as they see fit. The best way I could see to do that was via the methods I had above. But if you think there is a better way I would love to hear it!

Comment: If I understand correctly there is no way that deletion will fire just after `setSelection(e.selectionModel);`. The user probably select the rows and then click the delete button. If so, you shouldn't worry about the async because the state will updated before the user will get the delete button - https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-snow-jsxr8?file=/src/DataGridDemo.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a state variable is an async method.

This is where `useEffect` come into the picture. `useEffect` meant to run side effects when something changed. So

```
const handleRowSelection = (e) => {
  setSelection(e.selectionModel);
  console.log(select); // <-- The state is still not updated
}
```

But

```
const handleRowSelection = (e) => {
  setSelection(e.selectionModel);
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(select); // <-- The state is updated
}, [select]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sutherland-9ryyt

Notice the `useEffect` callback been called also once the component loaded (because `select` has been changed) but in this case it doesn't matter because it initiated as an empty array - nothing been selected yet.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/303669) the answer so it will help to other people.